# Displaying a single term of a custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, taxonomy

How am I able to show a single term of a custom taxonomy in Wordpress?

I have a custom taxonomy, which will always have only one term in it, and I want to display it in a custom loop on my home page. I have tried all possible ways, with one (blargh, can't remember which one) I managed to display the term but as a link, which I don't want. I need it as regular text, since I want to display it in my own href, which will link to the place where I want to.

Any ideas anyone? All and any help very much appreciated. This issue is slowing down my development of a custom theme. :(

Answer (score 0):

Get the single term object using `get_term($term_ID, $taxonomy)`, or alternatively `get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy)`.

The term object will have, among other properties;

```
$term->name; // the name of the term!
$term->slug;
$term->term_id;
$term->count; // number of objects using the term
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but it's not giving me anything at all. Maybe I'm using it wrong, but <?php get_term('taxonomy_name'); ?> isn't giving me any results.

Comment: The first argument needs to be the ID of the single term. The second argument is the term taxonomy.

Comment: If you just want to get the first term of a taxonomy, use `$terms = get_terms($taxonomy)`. The first term will be `$terms[0]`.

Comment: Still not getting anything, but probably not using it right again.

<?php
$terms = get_terms('issue');
$terms[0]
?>

Like this?

Comment: Yes, but `$terms[0]` will do nothing on it's own - how about `echo $terms[0]->name;`?

Comment: Thanks, man! It's working alright but it's not what I'm looking for. It's showing the term by ID, but what I need is to show whatever the term is in a specific taxonomy. I always have one term in the taxonomy, but each time it's different, so I'm looking for a way to show it.

Comment: I'm sure what I've provided is what you're looking for - perhaps I'm misunderstanding? Just use `get_terms()` to get all the terms for any taxonomy (even if there's only one term, an array is still returned), then use `$terms[0]` to get the first item.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks again, man. I will look into it, maybe there was something wrong with my loop but it was showing the same value for all of the items the loop got, very weird.

Comment: Just a heads-up, but `get_terms()` outputs an associative array, with the array key being the ID of the term, and the value being the term object itself. Makes it a bit tricky to grab the first one, unfortunately, as `$terms[0]` won't necessarily work, unless there's a term in that array with an ID of `0`.

Comment: @jeffbyrnes Nice point - though it should also be noted this is only the case for arg `fields=id=>parent` - I guess play it safe with `array_shift`!